# Почему flex items не центрируются равномерно?

Tags: css

Не могу понять, почему flex items не распределились равномерно по ширине родительского блока. Поскажите, что я делаю не так?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #676767;
}

div.main-product-card {  /*Define size of the main card*/
  border: 1px solid #ff6666;
  width: 385px;
  min-height: 25em;
}

.main-product-image { /*Define size of the main card image*/
  display: block;
  width: 14em;
  margin-top: 19px;
}

div.product-properties {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

div.product-properties ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

}

div.product-properties ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main-product-card">
<div class="product-properties">
    <ul>
      <li><small>Free shipping</small></li>
      <li><small>New</small></li>
      <li><small>00:02:29</small></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

уберите padding у ul

```css
div.product-properties {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

div.product-properties ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

div.product-properties ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-properties">
  <ul>
    <li><small>Free shipping</small></li>
    <li><small>New</small></li>
    <li><small>00:02:29</small></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!